# Headphone cables: Coiled v.s Straight

Tags: cable, headphones

What's the difference between the two? Is it just the convenience of one over the other or does it affect sound quality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I've ever heard it's just a convenience that some people prefer.  I do not believe the coil has any appreciable effect on the electrical signal.

Comment: I agree, coiled cables are general just harder to damage.

Comment: Just remember a coiled cable is longer than it appears.

Comment: Keep in mind, a coiled guitar cable might well degrade sound quality a small amount.

Comment: @neilfein Why is that?  Length?

Comment: @Warrior Bob - Correct. (On the other hand, coiled guitar cables *do* kinda look cool.)

Comment: Some people say that the swirling action as the signal passes through the coiled cable enhances the Tone, in much the same way that swirling a glass of wine allows the bouquet to develop.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, I thought this was audioPHILE.stackexchange.com :)